# How to find element by class in BS4 (python 3)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Website: https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/collections/jewelry/categories.viewall.html

Looking to scrape all information for each product and copy into excel file for further charting/analysis.

Been following the documentation here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Work so far returns nothing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString

url = "https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/collections/jewelry/categories.viewall.html"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

lst =[]


for my_items in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "grid-item"}):

    print(my_items)
```

Comment: The website renders the items you are trying to find using javascript after the pageload has "completed" via requests for your code. Using requests will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The page is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` won't support it. However, the data is available via sending a `GET` request to:

```
https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/collections/jewelry/categories.productlistingservletv2.json
```

The response data is a Python dictionary (`dict`), where you can access the `key`/`value`:

```
>>> import requests
>>>
>>>
>>> URL = "https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/collections/jewelry/categories.productlistingservletv2.json"
>>> response = requests.get(URL).json()
>>> print(type(response))
<class 'dict'>
```

---

An alternative would be to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

In your example:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://ca.cartier.com/en-ca/collections/jewelry/categories.viewall.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for the page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
driver.quit()

for tag in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "grid-item"}):
    print(tag)
```